# JS Как выделить оставить часть текста URL?

Tags: javascript

Есть строки, типа  этой:

```
https://www.ebay.com/itm/1X-Serial-Interface-Board-Module-LCD1602-Address-Changeableyq/152646941014?hash=item238a777956:g:J0YAAOSwcu5UNp~I
```

Нужно изменить к такому виду:

```
https://www.ebay.com/itm/152646941014
```

Что дальше, как сделать?
Никак не  могу осилить эти  регулярные выражения.
Может можно иначе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот, подсказали, работает:

```js
var url = "https://www.ebay.com/itm/1X-Serial-Interface-Board-Module-LCD1602-Address-Changeableyq/152646941014?hash=item238a777956:g:J0YAAOSwcu5UNp~I";
url = url.replace(/(itm).+(\/\d+).*/, "$1$2");
console.info(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так, к примеру:

```js
var s = 'https://www.ebay.com/itm/1X-Serial-Interface-Board-Module-LCD1602-Address-Changeableyq/152646941014?hash=item238a777956:g:J0YAAOSwcu5UNp~I';

console.log(s.match(/(http.*itm\/)/)[1] + s.match(/\/(\d*)\?/)[1]);
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Comment: @izhadapter, видимо у вас очень старый браузер. У меня работает даже на мобильных. Либо же вы вставили туда другую ссылку.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var s = 'https://www.ebay.com/itm/1X-Serial-Interface-Board-Module-LCD1602-Address-Changeableyq/152646941014?hash=item238a777956:g:J0YAAOSwcu5UNp~I';

console.log(s.match(/(http.*itm\/)/)[1] + s.match(/\/(\d*)\?/)[1]);
```

С этим  URL работает но с другими нет
в консоли  выдаёт ошибку почему-то у меня:
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Ну оно и понятно, тут вроде привязка к единице,а ссылки могут быть различными.